# How do I prevent UITableViewCell from changing after edit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

In the image below, I swipe the cell to the left to reveal actions.  Once the action is done, the cell adjusts back to normal... but not quite because the right side alignment is off.  I'd like to get some ideas as to how to correct that behavior.

Here is a screenshot of it with the view debugger to outline the objects.
[image]

As you can see, the left hand side is still perfectly aligned.  But the right hand side's trailing constraint is either disregarded (w/o telling me a constraint was broken) or some other thing is happening that I don't understand.  The position of the button on the right varies from far off to only slightly off.

My actions are setup using `tableView: editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:`.
Now, I get this scenario even if no action is taken and the user selects the part of the cell that isn't an action.

I tried to capture the value of the trailing constraint within the action, although I don't know if I am doing this correctly because the values came out the same.

```
FavoriteTableViewCell *cell = (FavoriteTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"Trailing Constraint before: %f)",cell.dragTrailingConstant.constant);
[self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:NO];
NSLog(@"Trailing Constraint  after: %f)",cell.dragTrailingConstant.constant);
```

Trailing Constraint before: -4.000000

Trailing Constraint  after: -4.000000

The trailing constraint is: Superview.Trailing.Margin Equal DragButton.Trailing.  Constant -4.  Priority 1000.  Multiplier 1.

**Edit:**

From a lot of testing with the simulator for multiple devices and OS versions, it appears that:

- This is a problem on iOS 8.4

  - With and without `canDisplayBannerAds`
- This is **not** a  problem on iOS 8.1
- I don't have simulators for 8.2 and 8.3 installed.